# Transit Visa Canadian PR travel documents in South Korea

Tags: visas, transit

I have plans to travel to India and have 7 hours transit in South Korea so I am a PR card and Canadian travel documents holder.
Do I need transit Visa for South Korea

Comment: What do you mean by 'Canadian travel document holder'? And what is your nationality?

Comment: Canada issues travel documents, which only say TRAVEL DOCUMENT (Convention of 28 July 1951) on the cover. These are, of course, 1951 convention travel documents. Recently issued ones are also biometric. But the OP got his answer and is probably not returning to this site.

Answer (score 1):

You can transit South Korea airside with a Canada 1951 convention (refugee) travel document and do not need a visa. But you cannot transit landside using the "transit tourist" program.

When transiting at Seoul, you can stay airside up to 24 hours between your flights. When transiting at other airports, your connecting flight must leave on the same calendar day.

Timatic states:

> TWOV (Transit Without Visa):
>
> - Passengers transiting through Seoul (ICN) with a confirmed
>     onward ticket for a flight to a third country within 24
>     hours. They must stay in the international transit area of
>     the airport and have documents required for the next
>     destination.
>
>   - TWOV does not apply to nationals of Egypt, Sudan, Syria and
>       Yemen.
> - Passengers transiting through Seoul (ICN) with a confirmed
>     onward ticket for a flight to a third country within 72
>     hours. They must:
>
>   - join a transit tour organized by Seoul (ICN), and
>   - have documents required for the next destination.
>   - TWOV does not apply to nationals of Egypt, Sudan, Syria and
>       Yemen.
>   - This TWOV facility does not apply to nationals of
>       Afghanistan, Bangladesh, Cameroon, Cuba, Egypt, Gambia,
>       Ghana, Iran, Iraq, Kyrgyzstan, Macedonia (FYROM), Myanmar,
>       Nepal, Nigeria, Pakistan, Senegal, Somalia, Sri Lanka and
>       Uzbekistan.
>   - This TWOV facility does not apply to passengers with "The
>       Palestinian Authority  passport.
>   - This TWOV facility does not apply to refugees and stateless
>       persons.
> - Passengers with a confirmed onward ticket for a flight to a
>     third country on the same calendar day. They must stay in
>     the international transit area of the airport and have
>     documents required for the next destination.
>
>   - This TWOV facility does not apply at Seoul (ICN).
>   - TWOV does not apply to nationals of Egypt, Sudan, Syria and
>       Yemen.